# How to fetch "To" information from email using ews in java

Tags: java, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

I need your help in Fetching TO information from the mail using Java.

I have got C# code, but dont know how to write into Java. 
For reference I am placing C# code below here.

```
Recipients = ((Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailAddressCollection)item.Item[EmailMessageSchema.ToRecipients]).Select(recipient => recipient.Address).ToArray().
```

It would be great if I can see this code in java.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the only property you want to read is *ToRecipients* (precisely [`EmailMessageSchema.ToRecipients`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.emailmessageschema.torecipients(v=exchg.80).aspx)) you can do this like that:

```
    PropertySet propertySet = new PropertySet(EmailMessageSchema.ToRecipients);
    EmailMessage email = EmailMessage.bind(service, new ItemId(emailId), propertySet);
    EmailAddressCollection toRecipients = email.getToRecipients();
    for (EmailAddress toRecipient : toRecipients) {
        String address = toRecipient.getAddress();
        // go on
    }
```

Providing a `propertySet` like above will enusre that the property *ToRecipients* will be the only one set on the returned `EmailMessage`. Thus the call isn't that expensive like:

```
EmailMessage email = EmailMessage.bind(service, new ItemId(emailId));
```

This would return an `EmailMessage` with all *[first class properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/email-properties-and-elements-in-ews-in-exchange)* set. *ToRecipients* is a member of them.

**EDIT**:
Caution: There is also the property [`ItemSchema.DisplayTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.itemschema.displayto(v=exchg.80).aspx). So asking in the title of the question for "To" is ambiguous.

Comment: @Karthiktn I'm glad I could help.